# How to compare values across multiple columns?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, compare

Assume all value columns have the same datatype.   I would like the highest of all values with the id in the results of a SELECT query.

Table Structure:

```
table_a: id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

Example data:

```
id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
2, 125, 256, 133, 400, 67
3, 14, 14, 14, 3, 6
4, 325, 441, 441, 975, 3
```

Example desired results:

```
id, highest_value
2, 400
3, 14
4, 975
```

I started down the path of a CASE statement but that got messy fast.  I tired a sub-select but failed in getting that to work.  Is there a clean way to compare several column values to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case [greatest](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions069.htm#i77473) function will do the work.

```
with t1(id1, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) as
(
  select 2, 125, 256, 133, 400, 67 from dual union all
  select 3, 14,  14,  14,  3,   6  from dual union all
  select 4, 325, 441, 441, 975, 3  from dual
)

select id1 
     , greatest(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) Res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
Id1 Res 
---------------
2   400 
3   14 
4   975
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. I feel a little silly having missed the greatest function in my search for a solution.